# Client-Side routing doesn't work between Dynamic Path Route

Tags: next.js, next-router

I don't know why It doesn't work.

When I have called `router.push({ pathname: '/user/a' })` to go to `/pages/user/[userId].tsx`  It routes by URL navigate.

But I `router.push({ pathname: '/user/b' })` to go to `/pages/user/b.tsx` It routes by client-side.

I need your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your `nextjs` module version to ^10.0.1.